# Ensure that path exists in a path tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I have a path tree stored like this:

```
paths = [
    {'path': '1',
        'sub': [
            {'path': '2', 'sub': []}
        ]
     }
]
```

and a some paths:

```
'1/2' -> ['1', '2']
'1/2/3' -> ['1', '2', '3']
```

I want to have a function that ensures that a path exists in my path tree and if not add it.
My current implementation looks like this:

```
def ensure_path_exists(path):
    paths = [
        {'path': '1',
            'sub': [
                {'path': '2', 'sub': []}
            ]
         }
    ]
    for item in path:
        for subitem in paths:
            if subitem['path'] == item:
                paths = subitem['sub']
                break
        else:
            print('item missing')
            # add it

    print('path exists')



ensure_path_exists(['1', '2'])
ensure_path_exists(['1', '2', '3'])
```

I'm done with checking if path fully exists in tree, but stuck on how to insert missing nodes into the tree.

Comment: That's very confusing code. I think it would be a lot easier if you made path into a class instead of a list of dictionaries of lists of dictionaries of ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to update `paths` in-place if no path is found:

```
paths = [{'path': '1', 'sub': [{'path': '2', 'sub': []}]}]
def check_paths(d, p):
   missing = []
   if p:
      if not any(i['path'] == p[0] for i in d):
         d.append({'path':p[0], 'sub':[]})
         missing.append(True)
      for i in d:
         if i['path'] == p[0]:
            missing.append(check_paths(i['sub'], p[1:]))
   return any(missing)

print(check_paths(paths, ['1', '2']))
print(check_paths(paths, ['1', '2', '3']))
print(paths)
```

Output:

```
False
True
[{'path': '1', 'sub': [{'path': '2', 'sub': [{'path': '3', 'sub': []}]}]}]
```